# Combinatorial interpretation of polynomials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, proof-explanation, binomial-coefficients

I'm reading a proof for the following identity:

$$\sum_{k}A_{k}(r,t)A_{n-k}(s,t) = A_{n}(r+s, t), \qquad \text{integer} \ n \geq 0 \tag{1}$$

where $A_{n}(x,t)$ is the $n$th degree polynomial in $x$ that satisfies

$$A_{n}(x,t) = \binom{x-nt}{n}\frac{x}{x-nt}, \qquad \text{for} \ x \neq nt. \tag{2}$$

The author starts off by assuming that $r \neq kt \neq s$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$, since both sides of (1) are polynomials in $r, s, t$.

**Question:** *I understand that we need $r \neq kt$ to prevent division by zero in $A_{k}(r,t) = \binom{r-kt}{k}\frac{r}{r-kt}$, but why are we also allowed to assume $kt \neq s$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$?*

Writing $A_{n-k}(s,t)$ in terms of (2), we have

$$A_{n-k}(s,t) = \binom{s-(n-k)t}{n-k}\frac{s}{s-(n-k)t}$$

If $s=kt$, then

$$
A_{n-k}(kt,t) = \binom{kt-(n-k)t}{n-k}\frac{kt}{kt-(n-k)t}
= \binom{2kt-nt}{n-k}\frac{kt}{2kt-nt}
$$

...which doesn't result in division by $0$ if $k=0$ or if $k=n$, so why is $s \neq kt$ needed?

Comment: No division by zero appears since $\,A_{n}(x,t) = \binom{x-nt-1}{n-1}\frac{x}{n}\,$ for $\,n>0.$

Comment: Thanks @Somos, but why do we change to $n > 0$? Eq. (1) is defined for $n \geq 0$.

Comment: $A_0(x,t) = 1\,$ and my alternative definition has division by $\,n\,$ hence $\,n\ne 0\,$ is required there.

Comment: @Somos, I see, but then would we still be able to prove that identity (1) holds even when $n=0$ or $k=0$ (since (1) is defined for all $n \leq 0$ and $0 \leq k \leq n$)? The author actually rules out using the alternative definition since it fails for $k=0$ (see Example 4 on [this page](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=x9AsAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=%22since+both+sides+of+(30)+are+polynomials+in+r,s,t%22&source=bl&ots=B-13K7P19H&sig=ACfU3U1YdoPPWQiYqymdm-gRYGMhKRE64A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWuLKqodv2AhXrSWwGHYaTAfgQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Comment: @MikeEarnest, PS I've corrected the post and added a link to the original text if it helps with clarity.

Comment: You need $s \ne (n-k)t$ for $0 \le k \le n$, and the set $\{ n-k | 0 \le k \le n \}$ is equal to $\{ k | 0 \le k \le n \}$.

Comment: Thank you @Zerox! That's a really neat observation. But I'm not sure I understand how that equivalence works for *given* values of $n$ and $k$. Say $n = 5$ and $k = 3$, then how is $s \neq 2t$ equivalent to $s \neq 3t$?

Comment: Why does the overall sum remain unchanged?

Comment: They are not equivalent. The reason behind the assumption is that you need them **all satisfied** (i.e. for all $0 \le k \le n$ the inequality holds) to make the sum valid.

Comment: @Zerox, I get that, but wouldn't replacing $s \neq (n-k)t$ with $s \neq kt$ at each iteration affect the computation of the overall sum? Like, for $n=2$, wouldn’t we end up summing over 
$A_{n-0}$ [for $s \neq 0$] + 
$A_{n-1}$ [for $s \neq 1$] + 
$A_{n-2}$ [for $s \neq 2$]
...instead of 
$A_{n-0}$ [for $s \neq (n-0)$] + 
$A_{n-1}$ [for $s \neq (n-1)$] + 
$A_{n-2}$ [for $s \neq (n-2)$]? These two summations don’t seem to be equivalent to me.

Comment: @user51462 The inequalities should be satisfied at the **same time**, i.e. the sum should be $A_{n-0}$ [for $s \ne 0 \cdot t \wedge s \ne 1 \cdot t \wedge ...$] $+A_{n-1}$ [for $s \ne 0 \cdot t \wedge s \ne 1 \cdot t \wedge ...$] $+...$ etc.

Comment: @Zerox, could you please explain why we need to take the intersection of all inequalities? I've never encountered this before. Also, I had asked this question in chat rather than in the comments section yesterday because of the "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" message, but the chat seems to have been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of *symmetry*. Somewhat more detailed the identity is written as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^nA_k(r,t)A_{n-k}(s,t)=A_n(r+s,t)\tag{1}
\end{align*}

From the definition
\begin{align*}
A_{n}(x,t) = \binom{x-nt}{n}\frac{x}{x-nt}, \qquad \text{for} \ x \neq nt.\tag{2}
\end{align*}
it follows the term $A_k(r,t)$ has to fulfill the restriction $r\neq kt$ for $0\leq k\leq n$.

> On the other hand, changing the order of summation in (1) $k\to n-k$ gives the same identity
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^nA_{n-k}(r,t)\color{blue}{A_{k}(s,t)}=A_n(r+s,t)\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> From the representation (3) we see that also the term $A_{k}(s,t)$ has to fulfill the restriction $s\neq kt$ for $0\leq k\leq n$.

**Hint:** A thorough introduction in working with sums is given in chapter 2: *Sums*, especially in section 2.3: *Manipulation of Sums* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
by R. L. Graham, D. Knuth and O. Patashnik.

Comment: Thank you @epi163sqrt. Just to clarify my understanding, we're not so much replacing $s \neq (n-k)t$ by $s \neq kt$, but rather just using the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^nA_k(r,t)A_{n-k}(s,t)=\sum_{k=0}^nA_{n-k}(r,t)A_{k}(s,t)$ to say that both $s \neq (n-k)t$ and $s \neq kt$ hold *at the same time*, is this correct? Also, is it this symmetry that the author is referring to when they say  "We may assume that $r≠kt≠s$ for $0≤k≤n$, **since both sides of (1) are polynomials in $r,s,t$**"? I wasn't sure how $r≠kt≠s$ for $0≤k≤n$ followed from both sides being polynomials in $r, s, t$.

Comment: @user51462: Yes this is correct. The author addresses the symmetry. We usually don't say that it *follows* that $r\neq kt$ and $s\neq kt$ for $0\leq k\leq n$, but we have *to assure* that $r\neq kt$ and $s\neq kt$ for $0\leq k\leq n$ since otherwise we have division by zero.

Comment: @user51462: Saying $r\neq kt$ for $0\leq k\leq n$ and $r\neq (n-k)t$ for $0\leq k\leq n$ is *in this context* the same. Note, we have due to *commutativity of addition* $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k=a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}+a_n=a_n+a_{n-1}+\cdots+a_1+a_0=\sum_{k=0}^n a_{n-k}$, which is just a reordering of the summands.

Comment: @user51462: Many thanks for granting the bounty. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since $A_k(r, t)$ appears in $(1)$, in order to use the expression $A_k(r, t)=\binom{r-kt}{n}\frac{r}{r-kt}$, you need to assume $r\neq kt$ for all $k\in \{0,1\dots,n\}$ because this is a restriction given in $(2)$.

Since $A_{n-k}(s, t)$ appears in $(1)$, in order to use the expression $A_{n-k}(s, t)=\binom{s-(n-k)t}{n}\frac{s}{s-(n-k)t}$, you need to assume $s\neq (n-k)t$ for all $k\in \{0,1\dots,n\}$, because this is a restriction given in $(2)$.

That is, the author needs to assume

> $r\neq kt$ for all $k\in \{0,\dots,n\}$ **and** $s\neq (n-k)t$ for all $k\in \{0,\dots,n\}$.

The point is, the above is equivalent to assuming

> $r\neq kt$ for all $k\in \{0,\dots,n\}$ **and** $s\neq \color{red}kt$ for all $k\in \{0,\dots,n\}$.

The reason that the second assumptions are equivalent to the first is that, as $k$ runs through all of $\{0,\dots,n\}$, so does $n-k$, so it is OK to replace $(n-k)$ with $k$.

The second set of assumptions can also be written as $r\neq kt\neq s$ for all $k\in \{0,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: Thank you @MikeEarnest. When you say it is ok to replace $(n-k$ with $k$, I thought that meant replacing $(n-k)$ with $k$ for *each* iteration of the sum, e.g. for n=2, sum over An−0 [for s≠0] + An−1 [for s≠1] + An−2 [for s≠2] ...instead of An−0 [for s≠(n−0)] + An−1 [for s≠(n−1)] + An−2 [for s≠(n−2)]. But Zerox said that the inqualities must be satisfied at the same time, i.e. the sum should be $An−0 [for s≠0⋅t∧s≠1⋅t∧...] +An−1 [for s≠0⋅t∧s≠1⋅t∧...]$ (see second last comment under my post). I don't quite understand why though. Would it please be possible to elaborate on this in your answer?

Comment: @user51462 I have already explained the entire situation the only way I know how, I have nothing else to add.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove
$$ \sum_{k}A_{k}(r,t)A_{n-k}(s,t) = A_{n}(r+s, t), \tag{1} $$
it suffices to define the ordinary generating functions
$$ f(z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(x,t)z^n \tag{2}$$ and
$$ g(z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\binom{(t+1)(n+1)-1}{n}z^n. \tag{3}$$
Using standard properties of generating functions,
equation $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$ x\int_0^z g(z)\,dz = \log(f(z)). \tag{4} $$
It is elementary to show that $\,A_0(x,t) = 1\,$ and that
$$ A_{n}(x,t) = \binom{x-nt-1}{n-1}\frac{x}{n} \tag{5}$$
for $\,n>0\,$ given the original definition of $\,A_n(x,t)\,$
as an $n$th degree polynomial in $\,x.$ This approach avoids
the need for discussing any possible division by zero.

Comment: Thank you @Somos, but I was hoping to understand where the $kt \neq s$ condition in the original proof came from.